# Prevent onClick while Activity is displaying Progress Dialog (Android)

Tags: java, android

An Activity I have makes an API call, while it is making this call the activity displays ProgressDialog.

My problem is that while the ProgressDialog is being displayed the page is still clickable, and if the user clicks on a clickable object during this, it crashes the app.

How can I disable the onClick functions of the activity while the ProgressDialog is running?

EDIT: I would like to do this without removing the ability to cancel the loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using this

```
progressDialog.setcancelable(false);
```

try this for Your comment

> You are trying to set just the Property of Activity. Instead Bring up
>   a dialog using ProgressDialog, so that Ui will not be accessible

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait...", true);
```

Edit: If you do not want to use ProgressDialog, get the Root Layout and call

```
layout.setEnabled(false)
```

Hope It Helps U

Comment: is there a way to do it without making the dialog cancelable? I'd like to still be able to cancel it if possible.

Answer (score 2):

dialogue.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)